# $R$ has no zero divisors . Let $a \in R$ , $0 \ne b \in R$ and $0 \ne n \in \mathbb Z$ be such that $na+ab=0$ , then is it true that $a=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (not necessarily with unity) with no zero divisors . Let $a \in R$ , $0 \ne b \in R$ and $0 \ne n \in \mathbb Z$ be such that $na+ab=0$ , then is it true that $a=0$ ?

Comment: What about $R = \mathbb Z$, with $a=b=1$ and $n=-1$?

Comment: @Théophile : aha , true , you should make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $R = \mathbb Z$, with $a=b=1$ and $n=-1$. Then $na+ab = -1+1=0$.